# grey out dropdown box on selecting only one of the radio button

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascripts, I am trying to modify codes on a form that includes radio button and dropdown menus, but I would like to grey out dropdown box on selecting only one of the radio button (electronic) selected.

Physical (radio button) 
Image (radio button)
Electronic (radio button)

Number of Boxes       [dropdown box]
I have 3 radio buttons above number of boxes (dropdown).  I want the dropdown selection box grayed out on selecting Electronic (radio button)

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="physical" value="physical">
              <label for="physical">Physical<br>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="image" value="image">
              Image               <br>
              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="electronic" value="electronic">
              Electronic
```

I want this grayed out on selecting electronic above

```
<select name="NumberofBoxes" onchange="javascript:this.form.action='RecordsTransmittalForm.asp';this.form.submit();">
                    <option value="">--select one--</option>
                    <%
                        for i = 1 to 100
                    %>
                        <%if clng(NumberofBoxes) = i then%>
                            <option value="<%=i%>" selected><%=i%></option>
                        <%else%>
                            <option value="<%=i%>"><%=i%></option>
                        <%end if%>
                    <%
                        next
                    %>
                </select>
```

Comment: Too hard to help without your example html code

Comment: @MichaelRobinson I've pasted in the html from the duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354311/grey-out-dropdown-box-on-selecting-only-one-of-the-radio-button) - HTH.

Comment: Where are the radio buttons from your description? Your html only has select elements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly mention whether selection of the other radio buttons should re-enable your select element, but I assume that's what you want in which case the following will work:

```
<script>
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var el = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if(el.tagName.toUpperCase()==="INPUT" && el.name === "radio")
        document.getElementById("NumberofBoxes").disabled =
                                                    el.value === "electronic";
};
</script>
```

Not the prettiest way to do it (and you should test for and use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or `attachEvent()`), which makes the code even uglier), but since you've not provided any source html or anything I've just attached an `onclick` handler to the body that tests whether the clicked element was an input with a particular name (where of course each radio button in a group will have the same name). If it was a radio that was clicked it enables or disables the specified select element depending on the value of the clicked radio.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bcqcF/1/

Comment: Please review as edited above, the suggested did not work for. Kindly re-visit the problem. I have edited the post to include the html code

Comment: If you update your `<select>` element to give it an `id="NumberofBoxes"` (as well as its current `name` attribute) then the slightly updated code in my answer should work - you _know_ it works in a general sense because I provided a working demo for you already. Note also that you have a `<label>` element with no closing `</label>` tag, which probably doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener to the radio button like:

```
<input type="radio" ... onclick="this.form.StorageType.disabled = this.checked;">
```

Of course you can add it dynamically but you haven't given enough information to do that, the above is just an example.